# WinForm Insert text in SQL table based on selection from DataGridview - text not in DGV

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a datagridview in my winform and I select a row within the dgv - send an email. I need to write to a sql table that the email has been sent (Ack column) and date the email was sent. This text is not in the DGV. I am having trouble doing this with the code I have. It doesn't seem to do anything at all - I don't see anything in the debugger either.

Here is my code:

```
namespace TTIdB
{
public partial class OrdrProc : Form
{
    public OrdrProc()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        salesOrdersDataGridView.SelectionMode = 
 DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
    }

    private void btnAck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


              using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=srv;Initial Catalog=db;Integrated Security=True"))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in salesOrdersDataGridView.SelectedRows)
            {

                cmd.CommandText = ("UPDATE table SET Ack = @Ack,DateAcknowledged = @DateAcknowledged WHERE orderNum = @Ordrnum");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ack", "Y");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateAcknowledged", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ordrnum", lblOrder.Text);
                cn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cn.Close();
            }

        }


        try
        {


            //Must add Outlook Reference Object Library


            Outlook.Application _app = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)_app.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

            mail.To = lblEmail.Text;

            mail.Subject = "Order Acknowledgement for your PO " + lblPO.Text;
            mail.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
            mail.HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>";
            mail.HTMLBody += "Thank you for your order!" + "<br />" + "<br />" + "Touchstone Order Number: " + lblOrder.Text +
            "<br />" + "Touchstone Part Number: " + lblPN.Text + "<br />" + "Description:" + lblDesc.Text + "<br />" + "Customer Part Number: " + "  " +
            lblCpn.Text + "-" + " Revision: " + lblRev.Text + "<br />" + "Expected Ship Date: " + lblshp.Text +
            "<br />" + "Quantity: " + lblQty.Text + "<br />" + "<br />" + "Regards," + "<br />" +
            "<br />" + "Customer Service" + "<br />" + "Touchstone Technology, Inc." + "<br />" + "350 Mile Crossing Blvd." +
            "<br />" + "Rochester, NY 14624" + "<br />" + "Phone: 585.458.2690";

            mail.HTMLBody += "<p>Web: <a href='http://www.touchstn.com'>touchstn.com</a></p></body></html>";
            mail.Display(true);
            Refresh();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);


        }
    }


    private void OrdrProc_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        salesOrdersTableAdapter.SO(_TST_TWIDataSet1.SalesOrders);


    }

    private void salesOrdersDataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.RowIndex>-1)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = salesOrdersDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            string cpn = "";
            cpn = salesOrdersDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["customerPart"].Value.ToString();
            lblCpn.Text = cpn;
            lblCpn.Visible = true;
            string ordnum = "";
            ordnum = salesOrdersDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["orderNum"].Value.ToString();
            lblOrder.Text = ordnum;
            lblOrder.Visible = true;
            string pnum = "";
            pnum = salesOrdersDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["partNum"].Value.ToString();
            lblPN.Text = pnum;
            lblPN.Visible = true;
            lblPN.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 192, 0);
            string desc = "";
             desc = salesOrdersDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["descript"].Value.ToString();
            lblDesc.Text = desc;
            lblDesc.Visible = true;
            string quant= "";
             quant = salesOrdersDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["quant"].Value.ToString();
            lblQty.Text = quant;
            lblQty.Visible = true;
            string cpo = "";
             cpo= salesOrdersDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["custPO"].Value.ToString();
            lblPO.Text =cpo;
            lblPO.Visible = true;
            string rev = "";
             rev = salesOrdersDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["custRev"].Value.ToString();
            lblRev.Text = rev;              
            lblRev.Visible = true;
            lblRev.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 192, 0);
            DateTime shp = DateTime.Parse(salesOrdersDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["shipDate"].Value.ToString());
            lblshp.Text = shp.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
            lblshp.Visible = true;
            string eml = "";
            eml = salesOrdersDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["email"].Value.ToString();
            lblEmail.Text = eml;
            lblEmail.Visible = true;


        }
    }

    private void closeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
     }
   }
}
```

I am using VS2015

UPDATE with this code: I am now able to enter in the ForEach loop and it does write to the table, but now, it inserts the text (Ack and Date) to all of the rows and not exclusively to the one I selected

Another Update: I was able to get it working - the code above should be ok - hope it helps someone in the future

Thank you in advance

Comment: What are the types of these columns as defined in your database ? you can check the return value  of the method cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() to get the number of rows affected.

Comment: First of all, make sure that the code inside of the foreach body is executed. If it is, then post here how your table is structured ( what types are the columns in it ), ensure that the column names are correct or does not contain any built in keywords, functions etc.

Comment: I inserted breakpoints and it does not go into the foreach body - not sure what to do about that...

Comment: Try this syntax: `Insert into tbl (Ack,DateAcknowledged) SELECT @Ack,@DateAcknowledged`

Comment: Have you set the property `SelectionMode` on your `DataGridView`? It should be `meDataGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect` or `meDataGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.RowHeaderSelect`

Comment: I think your sugeestion is in VB? I am using C#   Either way, I inserted salesOrdersDataGridView.SelectionMode DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect; and it still doesnt go into the for each block. Perhaps I inserted the code in the wrong place? I tried before the for each and after...

Comment: This should go in the `InitializeComponent` method and it's C# ... not VB. How are you calling this piece of code? Via Event or directly from the code, is debugging enter to the using SqlConnection block? You should really read on how to post [mcve].

Comment: ah - thanks so much for the suggestion on the posting examples. I have updated my original question to include the code - I think that is needed.  UPDATE: I am no able to enter in the ForEach loop and it does write to the table, but now, it inserts the text (Ack and Date) to all of the rows and not exclusively to the one I selected

Comment: @m.rogalski, I was able to solve the rest of the issues and the code now works. Thanks to your tip on the selectionmode which got me going in the right direction. if you can set this to an answer, I will gladly mark this solved and give you an upvote - thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Please add `SqlConnection` object in `SqlCommand` parameter. Follow the code:

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=srv;Initial Catalog=db;Integrated Security=True"))
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in salesOrdersDataGridView.SelectedRows)
        {                
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into tbl (Ack,DateAcknowledged) Values (@Ack,@DateAcknowledged)",cn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ack", "Y");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateAcknowledged", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
            cn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();
        }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the tips in the code - I can where issues were - but this didn't resolve the original problem

Comment: Code here sounds good. Please check the DGV properties. May be you are missing something. Also, sharing code for design will be helpful to detect problem.

Comment: Please check "SelectionMode" of DGV as @m.rogalski has already mentioned in comment.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't have selected rows over the datagrid view that's why the code does not step to the SQL command. you need to make sure that you select the rows you need to write ack for them on your table and check that your data grid allows selection.

Comment: How do you know that the code doesn't go into the foreach body? There's no such thing specified in the question.

Comment: In the question, there's nothing mentioned about exceptions that may be thrown due to connections with the database or wrong SQL syntax and due to it was doing nothing, I presumed this to the selection of the rows

Comment: I have more code that when I select a row in the datagrid, some labels on the form update and the information is sent in the email. This is how I know the row is selected

Comment: so in this case, please try to use exception handling especially with database logic and check if exceptions raise in the catch block, it may be due to the connections or the table structure and field types and if some columns don't allow Nulls